# Permanently Deleting Unused Excel Rows

Tags: vba, excel

When creating a blank Excel Workbook, the file size is kept small by not using all 1,000,000+ rows. However, once data has been added to all of the rows, the rows still exist even if the data is deleted out of them, resulting in a huge filesize. I know these rows still exist because of the size of the scrollbar and the fact that if I scroll to the bottom I end up at row 1,000,000+ which does not happen on a new Workbook. I guess this would be called the UsedRange in VBA?

I have inherited a Workbook from another developer which is in this situation and I'm looking for a way to reduce the size. I can copy the used data only into a new blank Workbook, but does anyone know of a way to reduce the actual UsedRange?

The following code does not work:

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range

    Set r = Range("10000:1000000")
    r.Delete

End Sub
```

Nor does highlighting the rows manually, clicking in the header and clicking delete

Comment: Try selecting row numbers (left most column) rather than cells, then right click and delete (also on left most column) to delete full rows. Delete rows, and that deletes all data and formatting that is associated with them. Also, this question probably belongs on other stack exchange, as it is not about programming.

Comment: use `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: Just delete unused Rows and Columns in each sheet (hidden too), and save the file. You should see a difference when using Ctrl+End ! ;)

Comment: @user3598756 : Seems a bit radical if you don't want to erase the data!!

Comment: @user3598756 I don't want to delete my data

Comment: @R3uK I've edited my question to show different attempts. Unfortunately deleting the rows doesn't work

Comment: @JiminyCricket : That's because you have to save the file afterwards! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open VBA and type ActiveSheet.UsedRange in the immediate window.

I added it to my right-click menu since I use it so often.

Edit:

Here's the code I use to add it to the context menu:

```
Private Sub Auto_Open()

On Error Resume Next
'delete the control if it exists
Application.CommandBars.FindControl(Tag:="MY_TAG").Delete

On Error GoTo 0
With Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls
    'add reset range button
    With .Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
        .Caption = "Reset used range"
        .OnAction = ThisWorkbook.Name & "!ResetRange"
        .Tag = "MY_TAG"
        .BeginGroup = True
    End With
End With
End Sub

Private Sub ResetRange()

ActiveSheet.UsedRange

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks! I thought UsedRange was just a function to return the range

Comment: No problem, I've added the code I use to add it to the context menu each time I open Excel (I put this code into PERSONAL.XLSB)

Comment: Note that this method of resetting the used range often fails with large ranges and recent Excel versions.

Comment: The compiler currently won't accept that "x.UsedRange" statement without assigning it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

To clear all unused rows and columns in all sheets :

```
Sub ReduceFileSize()
    Dim wB As Workbook
    Dim wS As Worksheet
    Set wB = ThisWorkbook
    For Each wS In wB.Sheets
        DeleteUnUsed wS
    Next wS
    wB.Save
End Sub


Sub DeleteUnUsed(wS As Worksheet)
    Dim r As Range
    Dim LastRow As Double
    LastRow = LastRow_1(wS)
    Dim LastCol As Double
    LastCol = LastCol_1(wS)
    With wS
        .Range(LastRow + 1 & ":" & .Rows.Count).EntireRow.Delete
        .Range(collet(LastCol) & ":" & collet(.Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End With
End Sub

Public Function LastRow_1(wS As Worksheet) As Double
    With wS
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            LastRow_1 = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Row
        Else
            LastRow_1 = 1
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function LastCol_1(wS As Worksheet) As Double
    With wS
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            LastCol_1 = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                                MatchCase:=False).Column
        Else
            LastCol_1 = 1
        End If
    End With
End Function

Public Function ColLet(x As Integer) As String
With ActiveSheet.Columns(x)
    ColLet = Left(.Address(False, False), InStr(.Address(False, False), ":") - 1)
End With
End Function
```